# WordPress Rest-API always returns HTML block and then the original Response Body

Tags: wordpress, rest

When using example.com/wp-json my response is as follows:

```
<html><body><div style="position:absolute;left:-12882px;width:1000px;"><p>phishing content <a href="phisihin external link" data-wpel-link="external">phishing</a>
phisging content </p></div>
</body></html>
```

After the HTML the normal response begins with

```
{"name":"Exampledomain - asdf ...
```

This problem only occurs when I activate the plugin called WP External Links, which automatically sets an external tag to that phishing ad

```
data-wpel-link="external"
```

It somehow activates that phishing link by adding the external link tag to it. However that behaviour is not present when working with the WP External Plugin on other WordPress sites of mine.

Somehow a phishing html link is injected to my wp-json response - it affects all Rest API Requests.

Any idea how I can detect where that phishing HTML ad is coming from?

Comment: "Any idea how I can detect where that phishing HTML ad is coming from?" Disable all plugins and activate one by one. Change to default theme 2022 or other. By this you can tell is it a plugin or theme then if you think its phishing if you use nulled plugin consider purchasing from the author or contact author if that is intended by them.

Comment: The issue is relative to the plugin "WP External Plugin" itself: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp-exernal-links-not-working-with-facetwp/#post-15422935 `WP External Links likely (negatively) affects many other plugins that rely on custom REST API endpoints.` the issue is marked as "resolved" but it obviously is not resolved at all.